# Networkx, DIAC graph, subgraph from a node with deph limit

Tags: python, networkx, depth, directed-acyclic-graphs, subgraph

I have a Digraph constructed with networkx that has 37379 nodes and 61263 edges. I would like to extract for a node target, a subgraph that contain only the target node and the first nodes that are linked to it.

I tried the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914920/networkx-extract-the-smallest-connected-subgraph) and it only drawn me the target node. Have i missed something ? I checked that there were edges in my graph ( i just output as json and saw "source and target" items)

Answer (score 0):

Please delete the question, it was a key type error as my keys are integers and tried to make a subgraph with string keys...