# Finding the node that has the most edges connected

Tags: python, scipy, networkx, breadth-first-search

I have sparse graph that has 508049 Nodes and 16751882 Edges and I would like to know the answer to :
"Which node should I pick, that would give me the most edges iterated during the BFS operation ? "

So in other words, I would like to find a specific node, when traversed with BFS would give me the iterated edge value close to edge count of `16751882`

I have the following code snippet :

```py
    G = nx.from_scipy_sparse_array(A)
    degreeView = G.degree()
    print(max(dict(G.degree()).items(), key = lambda x : x[1]))
```

Which prints out

```
(0, 66810)
```

Which when I test, shows that the node 0 has the highest edges connected to it and the result is correct with 66810 edges but there could be another starting node that could end up being connected to almost all the edges possible but might have less connected edges at the beginning of BFS iteration. I checked with networkx but couldn't find this exact behaviour I want to achieve. Is it possible to achieve this with networkx ?

From another question I got the following graph to explain it better ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/13917084/18248903)  :
[image]

So I would like to get the output to print for instance a node from the largest connected edges from the graph like `1` or `15` or `6` etc.